# Seeking map provider for Viewshed Analysis

Tags: viewshed, service-recommendations

I'm looking for a map provider that can provide viewshed analysis where I can drop a marker with a specific height and the map would show me the visible and non-visible areas within a specific radius. Something like this: [Viewshed Documentation - Code Sample](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/viewshed.htm#C_GUID-D9AA3117-6A84-46F5-907C-1D8E443D05CC).

Is there any open source map provider like OpenStreetMap that can provide a similar feature?

The link above is from ArcGIS but that's not free.

Comment: I think you can do a viewshed in GEE https://support.google.com/earth/answer/3064261?hl=en or QGIS https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis/ - I've not used either so I can't attest to their suitability. Getting elevation data to match your accuracy requirement is important: if you want to get a viewshed that could be ~30m from true location SRTM data is available for free but if you want to get 1 metre or less cells you will have to obtain *very* accurate elevation data which isn't often 'free'.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thank you. The use case is we need to drop a few beacons in a jungle and each beacon needs to see each other. So, I guess the elevation has to be accurate here... If I would like to develop my own application which will be offline, other than DEM file and the SDK, what are other things that I need?

Comment: A large spray of insect repellent and a computer that works in humid environments. A viewshed is calculated from a DEM and a set of observer points (where you plan to put your beacons) - then get a good GPS and not just a cell phone to place the beacons where their viewshed has been calculated and probably high up a tree if you can to squeeze a bit more distance and less interference from beacon to beacon. A surveyor may know a few tricks, for the cost of a few beers you could get advice that saves time and/or injury.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Lol! Thank you very much sir! You have helped me a lot! :-) Have a good day!

Comment: @MichaelStimson anyway not sure how to get your comments as the answer to my question...

Comment: You can answer your own question, now or later when you've got some screen shots or field photos to embellish your answer. It's fine with me if you want to copy sections out of the comments : comments aren't searchable but answers are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with your own DEM and offline by using gdal_viewshed https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_viewshed.html.

Answer (score 3):

As per @MichaelStimson I think you can do a viewshed in [GEE](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/3064261?hl=en) or [QGIS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ViewshedAnalysis).

I've not used either so I can't attest to their suitability. Getting elevation data to match your accuracy requirement is important: if you want to get a viewshed that could be ~30m from true location SRTM data is available for free but if you want to get 1 metre or less cells you will have to obtain very accurate elevation data which isn't often 'free'.